# Upgraded to XFCE 4.10, keyboard media keys no longer work

Tags: xfce, volume-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Volume keys are working in unity but not in xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137421/volume-keys-are-working-in-unity-but-not-in-xfce4)

I've been looking for a solution for this all night, to no avail.

I did a dist-upgrade from the Xubuntu default XFCE 4.8 (?) where the keys for controlling the system volume worked perfectly. Now, I have no idea what to do to fix this.

Comment: You are running alpha/beta quality software i.e. this is a testing PPA. This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).