# How to set volume in xubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, sound, xfce

I want to set via my Media Keys, so I first have to find out the terminal-command.

Outputs are:

**amixer set Master 10%-** `amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0`

**amixer scontrols** `Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0`

**amixer set 'IEC958' 50%-** `amixer: Invalid command!`

How can i fix that?

Comment: Has nobody an idea?

Comment: You will find an answer to your problem in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/a/224804/22537)

Comment: I read that, but do not really know what to do now. I mean the normal sound control is working. I have a icon in my panel with which I can control the sound. Also I'm asking myself how to configure the xfce4-volumed. It recognizes my mediakeys, but it changes the wrong soundcard, where the xfce4-mixer controls the right soundcard.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and changing the active card in the settings editor for xfce4-mixer solved my problem.

Comment: Now the keys work, muting works, but unmuting not. How can I fix that?

Comment: My sound is gone completely now. Even after unmuting via mixer and rebooting :-/

Comment: Are you sure you have the right sound card selected?

Comment: Yes. It worked till the moment i pressed "mute".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Volume keys are working in unity but not in xfce4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137421/volume-keys-are-working-in-unity-but-not-in-xfce4)

Answer (score 6):

You might try the command

```
$ amixer -c 1 set Master 10%-
```

The parameter `-c` specifes another audio card.

Answer (score 5):

If the packages `xfce4-mixer` and `xfce4-volumed` are installed you shouldn't have any problem:

xfce4-mixer:

This is the frontend for mixer settings delivered together
with the Xfce4 desktop environment. It does the same jobs
other mixer frontends do but is integrated into the Xfce4
desktop as a plugin for the Xfce4 main panel.

xfce4-volumed:

This is a volume keys control daemon for Xfce Desktop environment. It controls
the volume using multimedia keys, for the card configured in xfce4-mixer. It
also provides volume change notifications.

Edit: I was also searching for a definitive answer and ran across this http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=26844 which also lead me to see this https://github.com/smatting/pulsemixer

Now, the problem "Volumed points to sound card, and when I mute with Fn+keyboard, it mutes pulseaudio but cannot unmute it"!

So this issue was Solved using this application [PULSEMIXER](https://github.com/smatting/pulsemixer)

Comment: Both are installed, but it doesnt work. I see in the popup-are the volumebar twice changing, but it doesn't affect my sound.