# xubuntu volume multimedia keys not working despite changing the active card

Tags: sound, xubuntu, volume-control, notify-osd

The indicator applet works. alsamixer works. amixer commands work but they won't use notify-osd to display the volume levels.

I followed the solution present here: [Volume keys are working in unity but not in xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137421/volume-keys-are-working-in-unity-but-not-in-xfce4)
But it does not work. I restarted the xfce4-volumed. How can I know which card is it using?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the startup bug that affects several XFCE4 daemons: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1347272

If so, a workaround is to not start xfce4-volumed in daemon mode. Create a file `~/.config/autostart/xfce4-volumed.desktop` containing something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Hidden=false
Exec=xfce4-volumed --no-daemon
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
```